# how to put IF condition on <%=exception.getMessage() %> in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have used below lines in my web.xml so that if GenericException occurs in the applicaiton, genericException.jsp can be invoked.

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>com.example.GenericException</exception-type>
<location>/WEB-INF/jsp/genericException.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I want to display the exception.getMessage() on my screen only if it is numeric.
When I was trying to print it on the screen using  ${exception.getMessage()}, it didn't work

Instead, I had to use <%=exception.getMessage() %> to print the same on screen.

I want to print the same only if it is a number (error code basically).
My problem is that I am not able to check if this is a numeric or not. Can somebody tell me how will be the logic in jsp for the same.

Till now, I have put the IF conditions on ${exception.getMessage()} kind of variables using 
    c:if test =

But not able to put IF condition on <%=exception.getMessage() %>

Comment: if it is numeric..can you please explain that ?

Comment: I guess your `com.example.GenericException` has something like an `errorCode` attribute but you should post the code of it as the sentence 'if it's numeric' doesn't has any sense, we just see an exception and an exception is a class, not a number. Also, a pice of code of your JSP will help a lot to understand the problem.

Comment: numeric doesnt make sense, `getMessage()` returns string. You can use scriptlet `<% %>` instead of expression `<%= %>` and write any java code in that say normal `if(){}` and then use `out.println()` inside `if(){ out.println("output anything to HTML"); }`

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. I am able to code it using scriplet now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@page import="com.example.GenericException"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isErrorPage="true"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head><title>Error Message</title></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" >

    <center>
        <br><br>
        <table width="90%" height="100px"
               style="  -moz-border-radius: 8px;  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;border: 2px solid #467aa7;">
            <tr>
                <td style="color:#467aa7;">
                    <% 
                        GenericException e = (GenericException) exception;
                        int code = e.getErrorCode();
                        String message = e.getErrorMessage();

                        if (code != 0) {
                            message = code + " : " + message;
                        }
                    %>

                    <label><%=message %></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```